# SQL IF else select clause

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to do an IF ELSE in the having clause of a select statement.  Here is an excerpt of what I am trying to do:

```
HAVING  
IF      @Vendor IS NOT NULL 
THEN    (COUNT(Iron_1.SN) > 0) AND [User].UserIdentifier = @Vendor AND Location_1.LocationName = @LocationName
ELSE

(COUNT(Iron_1.SN) > 0) AND Location_1.LocationName = @LocationName
```

I want certain filters based on if the user provided a value for a query parameter or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead

```
HAVING COUNT(Iron_1.SN) > 0 AND Location_1.LocationName = @LocationName AND
        (@Vendor IS NULL OR (@Vendor IS NOT NULL AND [User].UserIdentifier = @Vendor))
```

or this slightly simplier version

```
HAVING COUNT(Iron_1.SN) > 0 AND Location_1.LocationName = @LocationName AND
        (@Vendor IS NULL OR [User].UserIdentifier = @Vendor)
```

try the two and go for the one you like the best and works

Comment: . . The simpler formulation is for the second clause to be: `(@Vendor IS NULL or [User].UserIdentifier = @Vendor)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, I'm just too used to the first form  :)